# Why is the PHP constructor a method?

Tags: java, php, python, constructor

PHP uses `__construct()` to set properties for a newly created object. From what I understand, it's not really a constructor, but a method. Why?

Also - for less .. inconsistent languages like Java or Python does the object gets instantiated before or after the constructor is called? And how is this different from the PHP way?

Thanks!

Comment: why it is not a constructor? It is automatically invoked when an object is created.

Comment: It's not a constructor because it does not allocate memory for the object.

Comment: In most of the languages I've seen constructors look and behave like methods, regardless of what they technically are...

Comment: @kindall: Guess what?  A constructor in a "real" language doesn't allocate memory for the object either.  The constructor is run *after* the memory is allocated, in every language i know of.  The constructor just initializes the object.  Constructs it, so to speak.

Comment: `__construct()` in PHP is just a curious looking method.

Comment: In, Python, you can control the creation of the object with `__new__`, but that's not really the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those languages instantiate it before calling the constructor.  In Java, you have access to `this`, in Python `self`.  Also, in Java, it's like a method, except with no return type.  In Python, the syntax is exactly that of a method (`__init__`).

Comment: Python also has `__new__`, which is called before the object is created.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually called a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), which are methods that automatically get called of certain "events". *Magic methods* are the closest thing to *events* that PHP has. [__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct) is automatically called by PHP on the event of class instantiation.

Along with the `__construct` magic method is the [__destruct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.destruct) magic method, which is always called when the script is shutting down, even when `exit()` or `die()` has been called.

I have found it useful to "play" around with these different magic methods, using multiple classes, to get a sense of what order the `__destruct` methods take place.

Comment: So does the HP in PHP stand for Harry Potter?

Comment: @appclay, no, "Home Page", from Personal Home Page.  But isn't that *more* embarrassing?

Comment: "*that automatically get called of certain events*". Which events are you talking about?

Comment: @Lion: Creation, (de)serialization, attempts to access inaccessible properties of an object, attempts to treat an object like a function...whenever an object needs to be converted to a string (for use with, say, `printf`)...and a few others.

Comment: @Lion I think he means events as in "things that happen" rather than events in the programming sense.

Comment: @appclay: Although these functions are "event handlers" in a very literal sense...

Comment: @appclay http://us3.php.net/manual/en/faq.general.php#faq.general.acronym

Comment: @andrewjackson, actually that's an attempt to rewrite history.  It's pretty lame that they don't even give the original meaning (Personal Home Page) there.  Unlike other recursive acronymns like GNU, PHP was not *originally* such.  They just couldn't think of anything for the `P` when making up a new meaning.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen, I am going to take offense to your statement. It is not for you judge, whether they could think it or not. Personal Home Page give good meaning and so that PHP Hypertext Preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

In every object-oriented language (that I know of; I'm hardly an expert in all of them), the constructor is called **after** the object is created, to initialise the *contents* of the object. No code in the constructor creates the object, or can in anyway influence the creation process[1].

(Note I don't refer to memory; in languages like C++ and Java "the object has been created" means the memory its fields occupy has been allocated, whereas in Python "the object has been created" means there is a dictionary that will hold attributes of the object once they are assigned)

In most OO languages that I know of, constructors also have extremely similar syntax to methods, and I don't see any conceptual difficulty in thinking about them as methods in most senses (in Python the `__init__` method is literally a method in every sense; there's just a protocol that the runtime system invokes it on new objects after they're created).

---

[1]Python has additionally a feature that *does* let you control the object creation process; but you don't do it with the `__init__` method (the special method that most closely corresponds with constructors from Java/PHP), you do with with `__new__`.